# Removing `AspNetUserLogins` table from ASP.NET Identity

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

As I won't be using any other login providers, I have no need for the `AspNetUserLogins` table. Is there any way I can remove it?

I've tried this:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    modelBuilder.Ignore<IdentityUserLogin<string>>();
}
```

but I just get a `Invalid object name 'dbo.UserLogin'` error whenever I call `UserManager.FindAsync(username, password)`.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you are still using the built in Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework.UserStore which expects those entities to be there.
The default EF implementation was not intended to configured in this way.

But the UserManager does allow removing most of the functionality you don't want, but you will have to implement your own IUserStore without the concept of external logins (don't implement IUserLoginStore.

Answer (score 0):

I know this has already been answered, and I think writing a custom UserStore is indeed the cleanest solution for removing it altogether - but if you want to avoid that, a **less clean, but workable** solution is to make a "fake" AspNetUserLogins view.

Example for **SQL Server:**

```
create view AspNetUserLogins
as
select '' as LoginProvider, '' as ProviderKey, '' as UserId;
```

For **Oracle and others:**

```
create view AspNetUserLogins
as
select '' as LoginProvider, '' as ProviderKey, '' as UserId
from dual;
```

You can do this for any Identity tables you don't use. It's still something sitting around that you don't really need, but imo, better than a real table. Again - not the ideal solution, but it is *a* solution if writing a custom UserStore is something you want to avoid.